Hölder regularity and Hölder condition
Is there any textbooks or papers introducing Hölder regularity and Hölder condition? When I read the paper(https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2021-374-11/S0002-9947-2021-08489-5/home.html), I found that everyone described it directly without citing or introducing too much. I wanted to understand these two concepts systematically.
Definition 1 (Hölder regularity). For $\alpha \ge 0$, a function $f$ is said to be $\alpha$-Hölder in $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and denoted $f \in C^\alpha(x_0)$, if there exists a polynomial $P$ with $\mathrm{deg}P \le \alpha$ such that
$$|f(x_0+h)-P(h)|\leq C|h|^\alpha,\quad\mathrm{when~}h\mathrm{~is~small}.$$
The Hölder exponent of $f$ at a given point $x_0$ is the maximal Hölder regularity of $f$ at $x_0$,
$$\alpha_f(x_0)=\sup\begin{Bmatrix}\beta\ge0\ |\ f\in C^\beta(x_0)\end{Bmatrix}.$$
Definition 2 (Hölder condition). In mathematics, a real or complex-valued function $f$ on $d$-dimensional Euclidean space satisfies a Hölder condition, or is Hölder continuous, when there are real constants $C \ge 0, \alpha > 0$, such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C\|x-y\|^{\alpha }$$
for all $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$.
